# How do I fetch multiple images from supabase storage?

Tags: flutter, supabase

I needed help in displaying all the images available in my supabase storage through my flutter app?

Would really appreciate it if y'all could help me in sharing some code snippets

I couldn't find any documentation or tutorials online

Comment: Stackoverflow is not meant as a place to ask for readily avialable code. Try something for yourself and if you have *specific* questions, feel free to ask a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.list()`](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/dart/storage-from-list) method to list all storage objects in a bucket.

```dart
final List<FileObject> objects = await supabase
  .storage
  .from('avatars')
  .list();
```

From there, you can either create signed urls and get

```dart
  final String signedUrls = await supabase
    .storage
    .from('avatars')
    .createSignedUrls(paths, 60);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Now how do I use the signedURL to display the image on my app screen?

Comment: The signedURL is just the URL of the image. You can use Image widget to display them. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image-class.html